# Laravel 4 how to merge database tables and order them by created_at?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have 4 database tables that I want to merge together, and than I want to order all the data by created_at field. With my code all data is still grouped per database table, the result should be some sort of timeline of all my tables data. What am I doing wrong? It is only showing 4 items...

```
public function showIndex()
{

    $users = User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    $projects = Project::with('votes')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    $events = Calendar::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    $jobs = Job::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    $all = $users->merge($projects)->merge($events)->merge($jobs);

    return View::make('users.index')->with('events', $all);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the only problem is the fact that it's not order properly, you can simply use

```
$all->sort(function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a->created_at === $b->created_at) {
        return 0;
    } 

    return $a->created_at > $b->created_at ? 1 : -1;
});
```

or

```
$all = $all->sortBy(function($result) {
    return $result->created_at;
});
```

see http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_sort

Comment: Alright, this solves my issue for the sorting, for some reason it is only showing 4 projects